# How can I avoid using eval() in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

Without starting a war on whether or not I should use `eval()`, I am trying to make a constructive discussion on how I can avoid (if possible) using `eval()` in the following scenario?

I am loading remote html templates into an SPA, to save calls I am loading json that looks like the following:

```
{
  "template":"",
  "contentScript":"",
  "viewModel":""
}
```

Where template is html, contentScript is combined script files and viewModel is a single script file.

**ContentScript**

When the json request is received (either from server or localdb) I create an anonymous function (so all variables are locally scoped to this template script) for the contentScript that looks like:

```
(function(event, view) 
 {
   // js content here
 });
```

where the event object is a shared object that the contentScript and viewmodel communicate over using a pub/sub pattern and the view object is the DOM element that is the template.

the only way I can see to get this pattern working is by using the following code:

```
var script = 'function(event, view) {' + json.contentScript + '});';
views[name].script = eval(script);
```

where views[name] is a collection of all the templates in the SPA so I can get them and rebind them easily given a name.

each time the view is rendered I can then simply call (to execute the script):

```
views[name].script.apply(window, [ views[name].eventObj, views[name].view ]);
```

**ViewModel**

The view model is a slightly different case as I need the properties on that object to be visible for binding, so it cannot be an anonymous function. To achieve the desired result I am creating the viewModel object as an object literal like:

```
var viewmodel = 
{
   init: function(event, view)
   {
      this.event = event;
      this.view = view;
   },

   ... other stuff
}
```

When the viewModel json is received I run a regex over it to ensure the init signature matches what is expected and then `eval()` it like:

```
eval(json.viewModel);
views[name].model = observable(viewmodel); // viewmodel var is available from eval'ing the contentScript

views[name].model.init(views[name].eventObj, views[name].view);
```

**new Function**

I have also tried using `Function('script as string')` which is also frowned upon. However this does not support both cases, as it creates an anonymous function around my anonymous function which requires an extra step of inspecting arguments to pass the variable down to my anonymous function. More importantly, it also hides the properties of the object literal preventing data binding from working.

**Conclusion**

I cannot see any issues with what I am doing here but am curious as to how this could be achieved using other means. I have spent considerable time trying different ideas and none allow both scenarios to work effectively.

Comment: Do you need to execute your code in the local scope? Is it alright if you execute it in the global scope?

Comment: I would rather local scope as there will be many templates and it will remove any variable clash that could occur. Feel free to post any ideas though as I may be able to adapt or I might have already considered and rejected due to some reason.

Comment: You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8RcDa/

Comment: If you want to scope it locally then there's only one way: `eval`. Everything else works in the global scope. I would however recommend using the global scope. If you're worried about name clashes then you can wrap your code in an IIFE: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: if your code works under "use strict" then it's probably fine. If it fails, it's not future-proof.

Comment: The `btoa()` approach looks like it has merit, albeit I can't see how to debug that approach. The IIFE is the same approach as it take with the contentScript as an anonymous function. This however, breaks databinding on the view. The ideal outcome is to have a unified approach to both script types in my json, so there is a standardised pattern to follow.

Comment: @dandavis, use strict is fine.

Comment: If you wanted to use `Function`, your code should be `new Function('event', 'view', json.contentScript)`. However it's still like `eval`. The difference is that a function created like this will run in global scope. If you want to run JavaScript code which you receive as a string, there is no way around `eval`'ing it somehow. In ES6 you might be able to sandbox your code in a [realm](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-code-realms), but it will probably take a while until we get there.

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah I did look over that spec to see what was coming. Thanks.

Comment: You may find this an interesting read: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: @Xotic750, thanks for the input, that is why I am executing in the local scope with `eval()`. I could of course use an IIFE (or globalEval) like Aadit M Shah mentioned and namespace it but I like the convenience of local eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid using eval() in this scenario?
>
> I cannot see any issues with what I am doing here but am curious as to how this could be achieved using other means. I have spent considerable time trying different ideas and none allow both scenarios to work effectively.

I believe the question deserves an answer.

As you want to evaluate your string of Javascript code in the local scope then I don't believe that using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) can be avoided in your case. One word of warning.

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.

Some interesting reading can be found at [Perfection Kills by kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)

Comment: completely aware of the implications of using eval, Function and the other compiler functions. The impetus of the question was to see if there was another way that I was unaware of that wasn't eval related. Thanks for the input.